# CSV Export returning index.php not able to download instead of open CSV file

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I have an employee record calling from another server using crul, process the result and  create a csv file and then offer it to download or open. but when i clicked to open it opens the csv file .html extension in browser and when i clicked on save option it says "Unable to download the index.php file from sitename.com".

Here is my php code for it:

```
    $url = 'sitename.com/myemployee.php?mid=101';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'; 
    $process  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_REFERER, "My_employee");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process);

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyEmployeesReport.csv');
    echo $return;
```

I am using Windows7 and IE 9.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is in $return ?

Comment: comma seperated values for csv files.

Comment: Have you tried to save it to a file and then use readfile() instead of echo $return ?

Comment: No! because i can not do that.Because this file has some confidential data and we can not allowed to store it.